# python executing a remote script in a different directory

Tags: python, bash, shell

Wrote python script to execute below after prompting for a username and password

```
./3rdpartyscript -u username -p password -flag 123
```

It works fine but the "3rdpartyscript" has a bunch of files it relies on and I didnt want to clutter the root directory so I moved everything into a folder. I also have no access to actually manipulate the script, only run it.

I can't get this to run correctly:

```
./folder/3rdpartyscript -u username -p password -flag 123
OR
/folder/3rdpartyscript -u username -p password -flag 123
```

I'm also taking the results of this script and using it for other things.

here's what I have so far:

```
6 def getCreds():
  7         global access_key, secret_key, yourName
  8         access_key = raw_input("Enter User Name: ")
  9         secret_key = raw_input("Enter Password: ")
 10         infoCorrect = raw_input('Is this information correct? (y or n)')
 11         if infoCorrect.lower() == "yes" or infoCorrect.lower() =="y":
 12                 p = subprocess.Popen("./3rdPartyScript -u %s -p %s -flag 123" % (access_key, secret_key), shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
 13                 output,err = p.communicate()
 14                 print(output)

I'll take the result of "output" and eventually put it against some kinda decision. 

 17         else:
 18                 print "\n Couldn't connect to please check your credentials \n"
 19
 21
 22 getCreds()
```

How do I run this script from a remote directory ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a remote computer, or just a different directory on the same computer? If it is a different directory on the same computer, then I would avoid calling it "remote" to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `cwd` argument:

```
 p = subprocess.Popen("./3rdPartyScript -u %s -p %s -flag 123" % (access_key, secret_key), 
                      shell=True, 
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                      cwd=YOUR_DIRECTORY)
```

Comment: fantastic, Just curious if I was not using python to do this and I was doing it in bash is there a "cwd" like flag I could use?